# Should Standard loopholes apply for all questions?

Tags: discussion

I'v seen a couple of posts adding this line to their questions:

> Standard loopholes apply

Shouldn't this be implicit for all questions? are we encouraged to edit these out?

Comment: There's a reason they're called _standard_ loopholes. ;)

Comment: I didn't know there even were standard loopholes.  What are they?

Comment: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default @rec

Comment: I agree with @recursive, I did a brief search and couldn't find the standard loopholes.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes, they are implicit on all challenges, so the link isn't necessary. However, I don't think the link is actually harmful, especially since new users won't be aware that there is such a thing as standard loopholes in this community. So if a challenge includes the link every now and then that might even help in showing new users that they exist.

Comment: Ditto this - I like to link to standard loopholes just so that new users are aware, because we do still get loophole answers every so often.

Comment: Wouldn't there be a way to customize the "answer" box so that there is a warning about standard loopholes?

Answer (score 1):

Standard loopholes automatically apply to all questions by default. It does not matter whether the question contains that particular text or not.