# Can the “How to Answer” pop-up disregard the association bonus?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, answers, new-users

[We now have a custom “How to Answer” pop-up](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11502/8478) (yay!). However, this pop-up isn't shown to users who come here with the association bonus from other SE sites. In general, this behaviour makes sense: the pop-up is the same virtually everywhere and it teaches people how the Q&A platform in general works, not how answers on that specific site should be written. However, as the custom pop-up shows, answering works a bit differently on PPCG, and we also get a lot of wrong/invalid answers from active SE users who are not familiar with the difference of PPCG from the rest of SE.

Hence, it would probably be helpful if this was shown to *all* new users, regardless of whether they come here from another SE with an association bonus or whether they arrive here directly. Since changing the text on a per-site basis was doable on SE's end, maybe changing the conditions for when it's being displayed might also be an option?

Answer (score 2):

The "How to Answer" popover on both Code Golf and Code Golf Meta will now show to all users who have 111 or less rep.

We are unable to make the differentiation between having earned 10 rep on the site (well we can, but it will have unacceptable performance implications). However, setting it to be 111 ensures that users who have earned the association bonus will still see it until they have earned 10 rep on this site.

This does mean that users who join CG without an association bonus will see the popover for longer. This was judged by the Mods to be an acceptable scenario in order to achieve the main goal of this.

---

> Came here with some rep?
> Still must see "How to answer"
> Until you do stuff

Comment: That's a nice haiku! Didn't know SE hired poets. Thank you very much